# Equivalence of complete norms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$ be two complete norms on a linear space $X$ such that if a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in $(X,\|.\|_1)$ and to $y$ in $(X,\|.\|_2)$, then $x=y$. We have to prove that $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$ are equivalent norms.

I know that if there exists $K>0$ such that $\|x\|_1\leq K\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in X$, then by the consequence of open mapping theorem, two norms are equivalent. But how to get this from the available information? Please suggest!

Comment: Is $X$ separable or does this furthermore hold for nets? Then the assumption just asserts that the Identity is continuous in $0$ and hence bounded.

Comment: It seems that some more works are needed? If $x_n \to 0$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm, from the assumption it is not sure if $x_n$ converges in $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm to anything at all. @SebastianBechtel

Comment: We may assume that $x_n$ converges to something using the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @SebastianBechtel You are right, you may write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We show that the identity is continuous in $0$ and hence bounded which is just the claim.

Let $(x_n)$ converge to $0$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$. By closed graph theorem $(x_i)$ converge to something in $\|\cdot\|_2$. By assumption this something is $0$ as well, hence $\text{id}$ is continuous in $0$.

For the sake of completeness: We have that $\text{id}: (X,\|\cdot\|_1) \to (X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is a continuous linear map between Banach spaces. By continuous inverse theorem its inverse map $\text{id}: (X,\|\cdot\|_2) \to (X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is continuous as well which yields the other direction of norm equivalence.

Comment: Isn't the same argument holds for general $X$? Where did you use that $X$ is separable?

Comment: In general spaces it is not sufficient just to consider sequences. If $X$ is separable, then further metrizable and hence sequences suffice. If we consider nets then we may deal with arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: But $(X, \|\cdot\|_i)$ are metric spaces already. Sorry but I cannot see why I can't just use a sequence here.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I have worked to much with locally convex vector spaces in recent time and there you have to take care on that point.

Comment: I could not understand how using closed graph theorem one can say that $(x_n)$ converges somewhere in $(X,\|.\|_2)$?

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I think it can be written much more clearly:
First show that the identity operator $I:X_1\to X_2$ is a closed graph operator (here $X_i$ is $X$ normed with $\|.\|_i$). Then, because $I$ is defined on the whole space $X_1$ which is Banach, use the closed graph theorem to conclude that $I$ is bdd.